# How to speed up group-based duplication-count queries on unindexed tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I need to know the number of rows containing more than `n` duplicates for certain colulmn `c`, I can do it like this:

```
WITH duplicateRows AS (
    SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY c
    HAVING COUNT(1) > n
) SELECT COUNT(1) FROM duplicateRows
```

This leads to an unwanted behaviour: SQL Server counts all rows grouped by `i`, which (when no index is on this table) leads to horrible performance.

However, when altering the script such that SQL Server doesn't have to count all the rows doesn't solve the problem:

```
WITH duplicateRows AS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY c
    HAVING COUNT(1) > n
) SELECT COUNT(1) FROM duplicateRows
```

Although SQL Server now in theory can stop counting after `n + 1`, it leads to the same query plan and query cost.

Of course, the reason is that the `GROUP BY` really introduces the cost, not the counting. But I'm not at all interested in the numbers. Is there another option to speed up the counting of duplicate rows, on a table without indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only goal is to determine if there are ANY rows in ANY group (or, to rephrase that, "there is a duplicate inside the table, given the distinction of column `c`"), adding `TOP(1)` to the `SELECT` queries could perform some performance magic.

```
WITH duplicateRows AS (
    SELECT TOP(1) 
        1
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY c
    HAVING COUNT(1) > n
) SELECT 1 FROM duplicateRows
```

Theoretically, SQL Server doesn't need to determine all groups, so as soon as the first group with a duplicate is found, the query is finished (but worst-case will take as long as the original approach). I have to say though that this is a somewhat imperative way of thinking - not sure if it's correct...

Comment: Confirmed: improves query time dramatically, although the _estimated_ query plan is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The greatest two costs in your query are the re-ordering for the GROUP BY (due to lack of appropriate index) and the fact that you're scanning the whole table.

Unfortunately, to identify duplicates, re-ordering the whole table is the cheapest option.

You *may* get a benefit from the following change, but I highly doubt it would be significant, as I'd expect the execution plan to involve a sort again anyway.

```
WITH
  sequenced_data AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fieldC) AS sequence_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = (n+1)
```

*Assumes SQLServer2005+*

Comment: Woun't work without order by, add ORDER BY (select 1), and in real its performance will much worse because of needs of sorting in Sequence Project, instead of simple counting in GROUP BY -1

Answer (score 1):

Without indexing the GROUP BY solution is the best, every PARTITION-based solution involving both table(clust. index) scan and sort, instead of simple scan-and-counting in GROUP BY case

Answer (score 0):

Speed and "without indexes" almost never go together.

Athough as others here have mentioned I seriously doubt that it will have performance benefits. Perhaps you could try restructuring your query with [PARTITION BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

For example:

```
WITH duplicateRows AS (
    SELECT a.aFK,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.aFK ORDER BY a.aFK) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM Address a
) SELECT COUNT(DuplicateCount) FROM duplicateRows
```

I haven't tested the performance of this against the actual group by clause query. It's just a suggestion of how you could restructure it in another way.

Comment: -1 No performance improvement, and not what the OP wants anyway. Also references tables/fields not included in the original question.